# To whom am I replying?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comment-replies, display-names

Here's another potentially dumb question.  As I go through old comments, I find myself to have replied to @users who seem to have changed their name.  Anyway, while I can guess to whom I was speaking, sometimes I have no idea.

Is it possible to change the @username in the comments when that user has changed his/her/their handle?

Comment: The feature request [Change all @username references in comments when a user changes their name?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31851/change-all-username-references-in-comments-when-a-user-changes-their-name) is tagged ([meta-tag:status-declined]).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @MartinSleziak.

Comment: The juxtaposition of the question title and the gravatar of Grampa Simpson yelling at a cloud is magnificent.

Comment: Now I will only be able to read Ron's posts hearing them in Abraham Simpson's voice...

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I promise, the next question I ask will have the title, "Should we be like the boy, or do we like Roy?"

Comment: @Asaf: When the gravatar changes, your comment will need to be auto-updated by the system....

Comment: @RonGordon, (or rlgordonma - your old username) I hope you are aware of this, I found it useful in such cases: http://normalhuman.github.io/oldusernames/ (Though running it on your username in Main Site took a while, with couple of wrong names, I guess due to deleted comments, still I was able to get some useful info!)

Comment: @JessePFrancis: oh my!  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @RonGordon Is [that](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22528/to-whom-am-i-replying?cb=1#comment88436_22528) a The Simpsons reference?

Comment: @BCLC: yes indeed.

Comment: @RonGordon How dumb of me to not google without quotes

Comment: @BCLC: http://www.hulu.com/watch/24537

Comment: There are some funny-looking comments out there due to the fact that one of our most prominent users used to go by the name "moron"... :-)

Comment: @matt That GR avatar is never changing if I can help it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This doesn't exactly answer the question, still posting my comment to the question as an answer, for future reference:

> Anyway, while I can guess to whom I was speaking, sometimes I have no idea.

You might find this tool useful to find to confirm your guess:

[Old usernames](https://normalhuman.github.io/oldusernames) by almost [Living Forever](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/147263/live-forever) NormalHuman (This tool helped me confirm my guess that his display name was changed last week, making this answer almost rhetorical!)

**Edit**: This tool is not accurate, for example, running it on Ron's profile gives few wrong names like "Chris", may be due to deleted comments, and note Asaf's comment below!

Comment: It should be pointed that this tool is not entirely accurate. I never used a different username, but it shows all sort of usernames when you put in my profile link. Including "downvoter" :-D

Comment: @Asaf, I mentioned that in the comment, missed it in the answer!

Comment: It says I have been Brandon, NeilTraft, user34377, minthao_2011, user52187, everyone, Q, LordBellington, Arthur, engi, and, get this:  NormalHuman. "not entirely accurate" would seem to be an understatement!

Comment: @GerryMyerson, something useful is better than nothing!

Comment: Tool works perfectly for me.

Comment: @Gerry: Had I known you were a Lord, I would have been much more polite when we met.

Comment: @Asaf, not possible. You were the very model of politeness.

Comment: Link on Stack Apps has a screenshot: [Find old display names of a user](https://stackapps.com/q/6276). Maybe somebody would be able to make a working version from the stuff available in the Wayback Machine [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160726060006/http://normalhuman.github.io/oldusernames/) and [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160208094202js_/http://normalhuman.github.io/oldusernames/usernames.js).

Comment: It seems that the link in the post is dead. I have tried to recreated it based on what I found in Wayback Machine. See the answer to this question on MathOverflow Meta: [Recognizing identifiable users changing user names](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4426). (We'll see whether somebody will have some suggestions how it can be improved.)

Answer (score 5):

Since the link in the accepted answer seems to be dead, here is a solution using [SEDE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info). We're looking at comment replies used below posts by a given users and after comments by a given user. This is by no means foolproof, but usernames of the given user are certainly more likely to appear in such replies.

- [Usernames used in possible comment replies to posts by a given user](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1117783/usernames-used-in-possible-comment-replies-to-posts-by-a-given-user?userid=111742)
- [Usernames used in possible comment replies to comments by a given user](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1117780/usernames-used-in-possible-comment-replies-to-comments-by-a-given-user?userid=111742)

To check for some specific user, simply run this query with that user's id. (For finding userid, see [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/help-with-what-is-my-user-id-and-how-do-i-check-it) on this meta or [a corresponding post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98771/what-is-my-user-id) on Meta Stack Exchange.) The queries are adapted from similar queries that I created for [checking possible username](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30738/is-it-possible-to-know-the-name-of-a-user-with-account-deleted/30740#30740) of a deleted user.

Answer (score 3):

An additional method to find prior displaynames is querying the PostHistory table. It holds for some events a JSON blob with the userid and displayname at that time.

For these events the Text column hold info on the user that voted:

- 10 Close
- 11 Reopen
- 12 Deleted
- 13 Undeleted
- 14 Locked
- 15 Unlocked
- 19 Protected
- 20 Unprotected
- 35 Migrated away

Here is that [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1279393/find-prior-displaynames-of-voters?UserId=1233251)

```
;with voters as
(
Select users.UserId
    , users.UserDisplayName
    , CreationDate
From PostHistory
cross apply openjson(Text, '$.Voters') 
   with ( UserId int '$.Id'
            , UserDisplayName nvarchar(150) '$.DisplayName') users
where posthistorytypeid in (10,11,12,13,14,15,19,20,35) 
and Text is not null 
and len(text) > 0 
and users.userid = ##userid?1233251##
)

select UserDisplayName
     , min(creationdate) [first seen]
     , max(creationdate) [last seen]     
from voters
group by UserDisplayName
order by min(creationdate) desc
```

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the educational [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the awesome [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).